# Make RaphaelJS SVG fill out entire container

Tags: svg, responsive-design, raphael

I want to make my page's full size SVG responsive. That means: 100% width and height should adjust. [The converter I used](http://readysetraphael.com/) apparently doesn't make the paths right, because even if I do:

```
rsr.setViewBox(0, 0, 2560, 1440, true); //or 1920 and 1080
rsr.setSize("100%", "100%");
```

The actual content inside is not resized. The SVG is resized and the ViewBox is resized, but none of the content is resized. Without changing the actual paths in my SVG file, how would I make it responsive? Example can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmvpq7a3/

Comment: Seems responsive to me, i.e. when I resize the browser the drawing gets smaller.

Comment: But it's not 100% width to begin with.

Comment: Looks like it is to me. It overflows the viewBox if that's what you mean.

Comment: @RobertLongson Maybe your screen resolution isn't as high as mine and it looks fine to you. That's what it sounds like. Even if it overflows, that's still not the intention. Trust me, it is not 100% width nor height.

Comment: change the viewBox values if you don't want it to overflow.

Comment: @RobertLongson To what, exactly?

Comment: to whatever you need so that the drawing does not overflow.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry, but you need to be a bit more specific. "whatever you need" in a case where we talk about responsiveness is not really ideal. Should it be set to the original ViewBox size of the SVG file? Should it be set to 100%? I honestly have no idea.

Comment: trial and error, I'm not going to plug in larger and larger numbers till it works, you can do that. Should what be set to the viewBox size?

Comment: @RobertLongson Is "plugging in larger and larger numbers till it works" really the only solution? Sorry, but no, that seems like an awful method. I'll wait for someone with RaphaelJS experience to reply. Thanks, though.

Comment: Robert knows what he is talking about. What he said is correct.  This is not a problem that requires any sort of Raphael knowledge.  Be careful about posting comments that come across as rude or insulting. You have no idea if Robert is a Raphael expert or not. If you don't understand how `viewBox` works, you can always read one of the many tutorials on the web. Or read the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#coords-ViewBoxAttribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `viewBox` is to tell the broswer/SVG renderer what the bounds of the content is.  That is how it knows the correct amount to scale the content to fit your viewport.

I'm not sure where you got 2560x1440 from, but obviously it does not match the contents of your SVG (the map).  The fix is to find the right values.  There are various way to do that. Sometimes you may have to use trial and error (as @RobertLongson says).

In your case you already have suitable values. In your fiddle you have:

```
var rsr = Raphael('container', '959', '593');
```

which is setting the SVG to a fixed width of 959x593.

To make it responsive, all you have to do is change it to

```
var rsr = Raphael('container', '100%', '100%');
rsr.setViewBox(0, 0, 959, 593);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmvpq7a3/2/

Comment: Aaah nice, you learn something new every day! Thanks a lot, Paul. So basically since the ViewBox of my SVG has a fixed size, I need to set that size to the Raphael container's ViewBox, so the SVG matches the size? That's awesome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your rephrasing. If you want the contents of the SVG to be scaled to fit your view port (the area of the page inside which you are drawing the SVG). Then you need to let the browser know which part of the drawing is you are interested in.  If you give it the wrong `viewBox` coords, then the wrong part of the SVG will be displayed.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I think I got it now. Thanks!